# Need help stepping through a java iterator

Tags: java, iterator

Say I have already created an iterator called "iter" and an arraylist called "database". I want to be able to look through the arraylist and see if any element in the arraylist is equal to a String called "test". If it is, then I would like to add the element to another list.

```
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    if(database.next() == test) { 
        database.next().add(another_list);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm completely new to iterators in java. Do I need to write my own iterator class? Any code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that every time you call `.next()`, it advances the iterator forward to the next position.  This means that this code

```
if(database.next() == test) { 
    database.next().add(another_list);
}
```

Won't work as intended, because the first call to `database.next()` will not give back the same value as the second call to `database.next()`.  To fix this, you'll want to make a temporary variable to hold on to the new value, as seen here:

```
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    /* type */ curr = iter.next();
    if(curr == test) { 
        curr.add(another_list);
    }
}
```

(Filling in the real type of what's being iterated over in place of `/* type */`)

In many cases, though, you don't need to use iterators explicitly.  Most of the Collections types implement the `Iterable` interface, in which case you can just write

```
/* container */ c;
for(/* type */ curr: c) {
    if(curr == test) { 
        curr.add(another_list);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: *The problem with your code is that every time you call .next(), it advances the iterator forward to the next position* That's certainly **a** problem.  Additionally, the adding is backwards: should be `another_list.add(curr)`.  The foreach loop syntax is `for (Type var : col)`, not "in".

Comment: @Mark Peters- Without any type information, it's hard to know if that's correct.  Perhaps the container is a collection of `List`s?  Also, thanks for catching the :/in mishap - I just fixed that.

Comment: Unlikely since he's comparing the element to a string for equality.  Either way, he said quite clearly that he wanted to add the element to another list, not add another list to the element.  I have trouble seeing the ambiguity.  Anyway upvoted because you caught the two "next" invocations which is a common problem among `Iterator` newbies.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(database.contains("test"))
{
   another_list.add("test");
}
```

1. you can use the built in method [contains(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)
2. you should use equals(...) for data comparisions
3. look at the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/overview-summary.html) to see if there is already a method present for your purpose

Comment: This is misleading - test is not (necessarily) a string in the poster's question.  Perhaps modify it to not be a string?

Comment: @nrobey: *"a String called test..."*  Now whether or not its value is equal to "test" is a valid point.  Should be `database.contains(test)`.